# How to connect and access On-prem SFTP server in AWS glue directly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, pysftp

Is it possible to connect to on-prem SFTP server directly in AWS glue job ?
The SFTP server has restricted access in this case (IP whitelisting)

Thanks

Comment: No, AWS Glue cannot access data via SFTP. Can you copy the data to Amazon S3?

Comment: Thanks John, is it somehow possible using network interface or something like that ?, i could see an aws blog on accessing on-prem db.

Comment: "AWS Glue can also connect to a variety of on-premises JDBC data stores such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, and MariaDB." An SFTP server is not a database.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue doesn't support connectivity to SFTP servers natively. You might have to use third party drivers or jars for this kind of support. I have added a blog link that might suit your needs here.

> [Connect to SFTP Data in AWS Glue Jobs Using JDBC](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sftp-jdbc-aws-glue.rst)

**Alternative approach:**
Since you mentioned "The SFTP server has restricted access" If there is no security concern to copy the data over to S3, below would be the possible solution for file based kind of source systems.

> Setup a scheduler or a process to transfer these files into S3
> buckets. Then AWS Glue crawler can be used to create metadata and AWS
> Glue jobs for ETL.